# Jquery date picker - want display date in an input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hava an jquery calendar:

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    minDate: 'today',
    maxDate: "+90D",
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    dateFormat: "D, dd MM, yy"  
    });
});
```

and

```
<form method="post">
        <div id="datepicker">
               <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker"/>
         </div>
</form>
```

I want to display the date inside the input field...Please help me

Comment: I think your code hasn't been pasted correctly. Are you able to fix that, and use the Markdown codes to make it look better?

Comment: i need a calendar that display one full month...

Comment: @Rob when u `click` on input field, calender  will be displayed there and u can choose any date and that date will be placed on  the input field automatically. where is the problem??

Comment: which plugin u r using??  is it jquery ui datepicker then see here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year  or see this http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline

Comment: no...not like that, i want to put calendar as <div id="datepicker"></div>...means display inline... and somebody clicks any date.... that date wants to display in an input field...

Comment: yes.. i am using jquery ui date picker...

Comment: @Rob update your question with all detail.. this is not a way to reveal ur answer

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you have duplicated your `id` value `datepicker`. It's there twice.

IDs are supposed to be unique (one per page). Even if you were using classes, you'd be calling `datepicker()` on both the `<div>` and the `<input>`, which is surely not what you want.

Just remove the `id` from the div.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wesley_murch/PMFwg/

Answer (score 1):

you cannot have two same id in a single page , use class for the same instead of ids

```
<form method="post">
        <div id="datepicker1">
               <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker"/>
         </div>
</form>
```

above will work fine as div id you can change to datepicker1 or custom it